# JTextField to read chinese character

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I need to read chinese character through java input fields. I have installed chinese 
in my system and I have set system locale to chines. I could type chinese character using
US key board in notepad. When type in my application I get only the english character. How to make java input fields to read chinese character. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make java input fields to read chinese character.

Perhaps it has something to do with the encoding of your text file. If I have trouble with encodings, I try and create files in either eclipse or OpenOffice, where I am able to specify the encoding. If you are on a mac, you can also use TextEdit, or (even better) Bean.

*edit*: I use *utf8* encoding.